# Why isn't self working in my code

Tags: python, class, self, arcmap

I'm writing some code to create a toolbar that edits a map in ArcMap and I'm having some issues with getting variable values from other functions inside other classes that I'm using.

All the functions are predefined so I can't change the `int` arguments or the code will throw an error. I checked the `dir()` and none of the variables I define using `self` are in the functions. I don't think I've made a syntax error and the code inside the other classes works correctly.

Here is my code:

```
import arcpy
import math
import pythonaddins


class findingCoordinates(object):
    """Implementation for leetScripts_addin.tool (Tool)"""

    def __init__(self):
        self.enabled = True
        self.shape = "NONE"

    def onMouseDownMap(self, x, y, button, shift):
        print "onMouseDowMap executing"
#this is where I declared the first two variables using self
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        print "Selected point is at %r, %r" % (self.x, self.y)
        pass


class squareFeetInput(object):
    """Implementation for leetScripts_addin.combobox (ComboBox)"""
    def __init__(self):
        self.editable = True
        self.enabled = True
        #self.dropdownWidth = 'WWWWWW'
        self.width = 'WWWWWW'

    def onEditChange(self, text):
        squareFeet = text
#this is the other variable I defined that I need to use later
        self.buffDist = (math.sqrt(float(squareFeet))/2)
        print "Square size: %r ft^2 Buffer Distance: %r ft^2" % (squareFeet,self.buffDist)
        print "self.buffdist is a %r type" % self.buffDist
        return self.buffDist
        pass


class buildingTool(object):
    """Implementation for leetScripts_addin.button (Button)"""
    def __init__(self):
        self.enabled = True
        self.checked = False
    def onClick(self):
        print "building tool is executing"
        #shows im_self, but no x or y
        print "%r" % dir(findingCoordinates.onMouseDownMap)  
        # Get arguments: 
        #   Input point feature class
        #   Output polygon feature class
        #   Buffer distance
        #   Boolean type: Maintain fields and field values of the input in the output 

#This is where the problem is. I can't get these values from the previous functions.

        inPoints   = (findingCoordinates.onMouseDownMap.x,findingCoordinates.onMouseDownMap.y)
        outPolys   = "U:\JackBuildingFootprints.gdb\BuildingFootprintsCopy"
        bufDist    = squareFeetInput.buffDist
        keepFields = true

        # Prepare the output based on whether field and field values are desired in the output
        #
        if keepFields:
            # Create empty output polygon feature class that includes fields of the input
            #
            arcpy.CreateFeatureClass(os.path.dirname(outPolys), os.path.basename(outPolys), "POLYGON",
                                     inPoints, "", "", inPoints)

            # Create a short list of fields to ignore when moving fields values from 
            #  input to output
            #
            ignoreFields = []

            # Use Describe properties to identify the shapeFieldName and OIDFieldName
            #
            desc = arcpy.Describe(inPoints)
            ignoreFields.append(desc.shapeFieldName)
            ignoreFields.append(desc.OIDFieldName)

            # Create a list of fields to use when moving field values from input to output
            #
            fields = arcpy.ListFields(inPoints)
            fieldList = []
            for field in fields:
                if field.name not in ignoreFields:
                    fieldList.append(field.name)
        else:
            # Create empty output polygon feature class without fields of the input
            #
            arcpy.CreateFeatureclass(os.path.dirname(outPolys), os.path.basename(outPolys), "POLYGON",
                                     "", "", "", inPoints)

        # Open searchcursor
        #
        inRows = arcpy.SearchCursor(inPoints)

        # Open insertcursor
        #
        outRows = arcpy.InsertCursor(outPolys)

        # Create point and array objects
        #
        pntObj = arcpy.Point()
        arrayObj = arcpy.Array()

        for inRow in inRows: # One output feature for each input point feature
            inShape = inRow.shape
            pnt = inShape.getPart(0)

            # Need 5 vertices for square buffer: upper right, upper left, lower left,
            #   lower right, upper right. Add and subtract distance from coordinates of
            #   input point as appropriate.
            for vertex in [0,1,2,3,4]:
                pntObj.ID = vertex
                if vertex in [0,3,4]:
                    pntObj.X = pnt.X + bufDist
                else:
                    pntObj.X = pnt.X - bufDist
                if vertex in [0,1,5]:
                    pntObj.Y = pnt.Y + bufDist
                else:
                    pntObj.Y = pnt.Y - bufDist
                arrayObj.add(pntObj)

            # Create new row for output feature
            #
            feat = outRows.newRow()

            # Shift attributes from input to output
            #
            if keepFields == "true":
                for fieldName in fieldList:
                    feat.setValue(fieldName, inRow.getValue(fieldName))

            # Assign array of points to output feature
            #
            feat.shape = arrayObj

            # Insert the feature
            #
            outRows.insertRow(feat)

            # Clear array of points
            #
            arrayObj.removeAll()

        # Delete inputcursor
        #
        del outRows



        pass
```

What am I doing wrong? Is this one of the rare occasions where I should use a global variable? Why is the directory not showing the variables I defined using `self`?

**Edit**:

I made this post a while ago and I just wanted to clear some things up now that I know more.

First:

This is code that is designed to be use with python_add_in. Python add in creates a toolbar based on some parameters you give it when you set it up, and whatever python code you put into a template it makes as a result of those parameters. That essentially means that all of the classes in the script above are events that occur when buttons and other toolbar objects are clicked or used in the toolbar.

Second:

The solution to this problem actually isn't in the accepted answer, my bad.

The root cause of the problem is that I was using class names that I declared in my script, `findingCoordinates` for example. python_add_in doesn't recognize these class names as the names of the classes it expects to receive based on the template you fill out before you start coding.

With that in mind, the issue was that I was trying to call classes that just didn't exist as far as python_add_in was concerned. The solution is to just go ahead and use the class names python_add_in tool expects you to use. These names are in the docstring located below the class definition so where I have `findingCoordinates` I should have `Tool`.

I hope this helps.

Comment: What do you expect your code to do, and what is it doing?

Comment: What is the input and what is the error thrown ?

Comment: @muraveill It's user input. That's working fine. The error thrown when I try to call it in the third class is an attribute error. It says that there isn't an x in findingCoordinates.onMouseDownMap.x

Comment: @glibdud it draws a square buffer of user defined area around the centeroid of a parcel. I expect my code as is to get the variable values from the other classes, but that's not working

Comment: You seem to expect `print "%r" % dir(findingCoordinates.onMouseDownMap)` to show you the parameters (`x`, `y`, etc.), but those don't exist until you actually create an instance and call the function (and then check the `dir` of the instance).

Comment: @glibdud where should I create the instance? I've never heard of this before. Is there a resource about this you can point me towards?

Comment: Not sure, maybe the [Data Model](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html) documentation somewhere? It's easy to demonstrate. Make a trivial function, like `def test(x): pass`, and then try to find `x` anywhere in `dir(test)`. (Or a trivial class, if you want to be closer to matching this case.)

Comment: @glibdud I did some reading and I have instances in the class that I wrote the functions in. Does this mean that I need to reuse the functions in the third class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`self` refers to an instance of the class that you've defined, so to access those values, you need to create an instance of the class, call the method, and then access the values from the instance.

For example:

```
In [9]: %paste
class findingCoordinates(object):
    """Implementation for leetScripts_addin.tool (Tool)"""

    def __init__(self):
        self.enabled = True
        self.shape = "NONE"

    def onMouseDownMap(self, x, y, button, shift):
        print "onMouseDowMap executing"
#this is where I declared the first two variables using self
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        print "Selected point is at %r, %r" % (self.x, self.y)
        pass

## -- End pasted text --

In [10]: f = findingCoordinates()

In [11]: f.onMouseDownMap(x=1, y=2, button="button", shift="shift")
onMouseDowMap executing
Selected point is at 1, 2

In [12]: f.x
Out[12]: 1

In [13]: f.y
Out[13]: 2
```

EDIT: It seems like you've had some confusion about scoping/namespaces as well. There's no `x` or `y` defined globally; they just exist within the class instances. That will also allow you to have separate `x` and `y` values for different instances of the class.

```
In [14]: x
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-401b30e3b8b5> in <module>()
----> 1 x

NameError: name 'x' is not defined

In [15]: y
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-009520053b00> in <module>()
----> 1 y

NameError: name 'y' is not defined

In [16]: g = findingCoordinates()

In [17]: g.onMouseDownMap(100,200,0,0)
onMouseDowMap executing
Selected point is at 100, 200

In [18]: f.x, f.y
Out[18]: (1, 2)

In [19]: g.x, g.y
Out[19]: (100, 200)
```

Comment: does it matter where I set the function equal to a variable?

Comment: How does In[11] give me the values from In[9]?

Comment: onMouseDownMap happens when the mouse is clicked down on a map. I'm no genius, but this looks like you're just putting in variables to the funciton and then calling them out immediately. How does this return the variables calculated in the first instance in the class itself?

Comment: If `onMouseDownMap` is being called when you click something, it would also be doing this on an instantiated `findingCoordinates` object, so my call in `In [11]` is just a simulation of a mouse click. You'd need to find the object instance to get the x and y values out of it.

Comment: Also, I'd recommend reading up on working with Python objects in general. From your code and comments, it looks like you may have a few fundamental misunderstandings about classes and methods that will make it tough for you to get this working.

Comment: Thank I'll work on it, but I'm having problems getting this to work out. I tried creating instances and I haven't gotten anything to work out yet. Can you recommend any good sources? I don't understand how this isn't just a long way of writing x = 1, y = 2. I tried this in my code and it returns "SyntaxError: non-keyword arg after keyword arg". If create an instance without defining x and y I get the same error I got before.

Comment: [This blog post](https://jeffknupp.com/blog/2014/06/18/improve-your-python-python-classes-and-object-oriented-programming/) seems like a good starting point to read up. Most of the rest of what you've said makes it sound like you're not making a distinction between the method arguments `x` and `y and the instance attributes `f.x`and `f.y` (which are set with the `self.x` and `self.y` lines). I'll make a quick edit to demonstrate the difference there.

Comment: turns out that I was using the wrong variable names for the classes. The tool that I used (Python add-in) set the variable names to the classes as tool and combobox lol.

Comment: Glad you got it resolved. It can be tough to debug things when there's a lot of interaction between different parts of the application like it sounds like there was here.